# GTM : Data layer AddProduct not going into to GA

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, prestashop, google-tag-manager

I just installed an `addToCart` event that appears like this in the preview function of Google Tag Manager :

```
{
  event: 'addToCart',
  ecommerce: {
    currencyCode: 'EUR',
    add: {
       products: [{
           id: '6', 
           price: 30.5, 
           variant: '31', 
           quantity: '1'
       }]
     }
  }
}
```

The problem is that nothing appears in Google Analytics eCommerce features in Product Adds.

Anyone know why? I call the function directly in the addcart.js in Prestashop.

Edit: Here is the full code:

```
sendToGA : function(id_product, id_combination, quantity, price){
   dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'addToCart',
      'ecommerce': {
         'currencyCode': 'EUR',
         'add': {
            'products': [{
               'id': id_product, 
               'price': price,
               'variant': id_combination,
               'quantity': quantity
            }]
         }
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: Are you pushing this through the dataLayer with `dataLayer.push()`? It's not obvious in your code. Also note that it takes up to 24 hours for data to appear in your reports, but you can use GA Debugger to check to see if the hits go through, or analyse your Network tab.

Comment: Here is my full code :
sendToGA : function(id_product, id_combination, quantity, price){
dataLayer.push({
'event': 'addToCart',
'ecommerce': {
 'currencyCode': 'EUR',
'add': {                             
'products': [{                        
'id': id_product,
'price': price,
'variant': id_combination,
'quantity': quantity  }]    }  }});}, 
I have this in my GA debugger : 
Running command: ga("gtm1452587844800.ec:addProduct", {id: 7, price: 19.681187, category: "Robes d'été", name: "Robe en mousseline imprimée - Taille : L, Couleur : Vert"}

Answer (score 0):

The dataLayer.push() looks correct. Did you add a GA Event tag to your live container version that fires based on a custom event trigger set to "addToCart" and that is configured with the following options?

> Enable Enhanced Ecommerce Features: true
>
> Use Data Layer: true

For instructions see :https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#add

Also, ga-debug is a useful Chrome plugin to see if your tag is actually sending data to GA, and what it is sending.

Comment: Thank for your answer. In Google Tag assistant recordings I go this : 
{"event" : "addToCart" ,"ecommerce" :{"currencyCode" : "EUR" ,"add" : {"products" : [{"id" : "7" ,"price" : 16.4 ,"variant" : "34" ,"quantity" : "1"}
after the detail view of th products, and this in ga-debug : Running command: ga("gtm1452588738034.ec:addProduct", {id: 7, price: 19.681187, category: "Robes d'été", name: "Robe en mousseline imprimée - Taille : L, Couleur : Vert"}).  Compare to: "gtm1452588738034.send", "pageview" I don't have details if I click on the left pointer. Maybe it's not sending ?

Comment: Product List views (impressions), clicks, and add to carts only show up in the Product List Performance report. If you are not setting a product list value, you need to set the Primary Dimension in that report to Product SKU (the `id` field).
Also, 'price' should be a string representation of a number with 2 decimals, e.g. `"19.99"`.